# Making cell content in Word table Bold or Underlined C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, cell

i have some problems with formating specific cell text in word table (having text in bold or underlined) here is my code(I would like to make "Objekt" typed B or U Thanks`objTable.Cell(0, 0).Range.Text= ("Objekt");`

Comment: What you have tried??

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
Word.Range rBold = mdocWord.Range(2,3);
rBold.Bold = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help immensely if you would expound on your question, 
but looking at the MSDN article on the Range properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range_properties(v=office.14).aspx), I have learned better how the class works. It looks like what Smit Patel has should work. But honestly I would try just use:

```
    var B = 0; //Initiate as false
    if(should be bold)
    {
       B = 1;
    }
    else
    {
       B = 0;
    }
    objTable.Cell(0, 0).Range.bold = B;
```

I am not one hundred percent on this but combined with Smit and what I have read on MSDN this should work unless we are misunderstanding your question entirely.

I wish you the best of luck, and I hope this helps, 
Remember MSDN is your friend when it comes to .NET

Andrew

:)